# Unable to install mod_wsgi on CentOS 5.5 VPS

Tags: centos, vps, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi on my VPS, but it won't work. This is what I am doing:

```
wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-2.5.tar.gz
tar xzvf mod_wsgi-2.5.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-2.5

./configure --with-python=/opt/python2.5/bin/python
```

After I run the above command, I get this error:

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 1298: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1298: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1299: /: is a directory

./configure: line 1461: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

Through some research I've discovered that I need to modify my command:

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
--with-python=/usr/local/bin/python
```

But, /usr/local/apache/ doesn't exist, or so that's what it is telling me. If it doesn't exist, how do I create it with all the files needed, or if apache is located elsewhere on my VPS where would it be located?

I'd also like to mention that I ran a command to install apache before this entire deal:

```
yum install httpd
```

so I assumed that was all I needed but apparently not (I am very new at all this server administration stuff so please be gentle)

EDIT: This is the tutorial that I have been using to get this all set up: http://binarysushi.com/blog/2009/aug/19/CentOS-5-3-python-2-5-virtualevn-mod-wsgi-and-mod-rpaf/

I got stuck at the heading "Installing mod_wsgi"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

mod_wsgi is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Once configured, you will be able to install it via yum as well.

Edit:
[Direct link to instructions on adding the EPEL repo](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F).

Comment: The reason I am doing this entire tutorial is because when I tried 'yum install mod_wsgi' it said that there was no package called mod_wsgi...I looked in the EPEL file list and there is 49 files that have mod_wsgi in their title...

Comment: I have no idea how to install it..any suggestions?

Comment: ... Follow the link that says "How to use EPEL" on the page?